# Mode of function kstest in module scipy.stats.stats

Tags: hypothesis-testing, scipy

In the function kstest in module scipy.stats.stats, there are two options for the mode, described in the help file:

```
mode : 'approx' (default) or 'asymp', optional
        Defines the distribution used for calculating the p-value.

   - 'approx' : use approximation to exact distribution of test statistic
   - 'asymp' : use asymptotic distribution of test statistic
```

Two questions:

1. When would you opt for the asymp option, in particular would it be if you are testing an empirical distribution with a lot of data?
2. Is this something that is offered in many other statistical tests, and if so is there some general guidance for choosing between approximation and asymptotic distributions of the test statistic?